# How to show a $C^2$ real-valued harmonic function is $C^\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

We let u be a $C^2$ real-valued harmonic function on a domain $U\subset C$, and I want to show u is $C^\infty$ on U.

Answer (score 2):

One answer is: $u$ is locally its Poisson integral over spheres. The Poisson integral of a continuous function, or even an $L^1$ function, can be differentiated under the integral sign repeatedly. In fact the Poisson integral of that function is real-analytic.

Answer (score 2):

The property of being $C^{\infty}$ is local. So, for any point $p\in U$ we can find a simply connected neighborhood $V$ of $p$ (with $V \subset U$). On this neighborhood we can find a harmonic conjugate $v_V$ of $u$ (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate). Then $f:= u+iv_V$ is holomorphic on $V$, thus analytic and in particular $C^{\infty}$. Hence both $u$ and $v_V$ are also $C^{\infty}$ on $V$. Hence $u$ is (everywhere) $C^{\infty}$.